# How do I convert a nested array of Woocommerce products into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to access the stock_quantity, ID and SKU for woocommerce products in a php array.

I need to get the SKU to compare it against a value in my JavaScript code so that I can display the stock_quantity for the selected product and update an add to cart link with the selected product ID.

I am getting the products by creating a query that returns any product with a SKU containing the $tag variable I am passing it like this:

```
// Get any products with SKU that includes tag
$query = new WC_Product_Query();
$query->set( 'sku', $tag );
$products = $query->get_products();
```

Ideally I would like to convert this php array into a javacript array with all the nested arrays/objects in tact. This snippet will successfully log the array to the console and I can see that the array does in fact contain the products I need access to.

```
echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode(var_export($products, true)).");</script>";
```

If its not possible to simply convert the array and all the nested content into a javscript array, Im wondering if perhaps there is a way to recursively loop through the php array and push the content to a javascript array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is my first stack overflow post!

Comment: json_encode the actual data structure then, and not its var_export (which would be PHP code again) ...?

Comment: I have tried logging json_encode($products) however it returns an array with empty objects like [{}, {}]

Comment: Probably because the properties of the products are private or protected - so json_encode can't access them. In that case, you will have to loop over your products, extract the data you are interested in from them using the appropriate getter methods, stick that data into an array, and then pass that to the client as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, just got it working! Will post the working code so hopefully it can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from php to javascript you can use such a thing.

In php:

```
$vars = [
    'data1' => ["first" => 1, "second" => 2],
     ... some many proprieties
];

wp_localize_script('name_of_script', 'name_of_variables', $vars);
```

In javascript :

```
 console.log(name_of_variables.data1)
```

Maybe the IDE will tell you that he cannot find the variable, because the variable is in PHP page.
Then in javascript you can use it as you like

I hope it will be useful to you
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no one was albe to provide a snippet but I was able to come up with a solution, so here it is:

```
// Get any products with SKU that includes tag
$query = new WC_Product_Query();
$query->set( 'sku', $tag );
$products = $query->get_products();
// Initialize an empty array
$products_arr = array();    
// Loop through products
foreach($products as $product){
// Create an empty object for each product
        $prod = new stdClass();
// Set get product data and add to object
        $prod->stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $prod->sku = $product->get_sku();
        $prod->id = $product->get_id();
        $prod->price = $product->get_price();
// Push product object with data to array
        array_push($products_arr, $prod);
}
// Create JS var and set it to the array of objects
echo  "<script>var ticketsBySku = ".json_encode($products_arr).";</script>";
```

Now I have a js variable that I can access anywhere in my code that contains the content from my woocommerce products query (php array)

Hope that helps somebody!